# jQuery Result's Field Auto Populating

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jQuery, and couldn't quite find the answer I was looking for when searching in here. I am trying to get 3 fields all using the class `.userInput` to auto populate to the `#result` field while the user is filling those `.userInput` fields out. I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Stats -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var autoLoan = function(principal, interestRate, termLength) {
            var result = principal + (principal * interestRate) / termLength
            console.log("Autoloan called, result is " + result);
            return result;
        }

        $("#get_started").click(function() {
            $("#entries").removeAttr("hidden");
            $(this).remove();
        });

        $(".userInput").keyup(function() {
            var principal = $("#loanAmount").val() || 0;
            var interestRate = $("#interestRate").val() || 0;
            var termLength = $("#loanTerm").val() || 0;
            $("#result").keyup(function() {
                $("#userInput").val();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it! It is not too far from what you have already

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var autoLoan = function( principal, interestRate, termLength ){ 
        var result = principal + (principal * interestRate) / termLength
        console.log("Autoloan called, result is " + result);
        return result;
    }

    $("#get_started").click( function(){
        $("#entries").removeAttr("hidden");
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $(".userInput").keyup( function() {
        var principal = $("#loanAmount").val() || 0;
        var interestRate = $("#interestRate").val() || 0;
        var termLength = $("#loanTerm").val() || 0;
        $("#result").val(autoloan(principal, interestRate, termLength));
    });
});
```

Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: Thank you so much, I had tried  $("#result").value = autoloan(principal, interestRate, termLength); in a previous attempt. Glad to know I was close and thank you for your help!

Comment: Perfect, be sure to choose a solution once everything is working :)